# php string to date conversion from multiple date format

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-formatting, string-to-datetime

I want to convert the string date to following format 'Y-m-d' from multiple date format like for example

12-3-17,
12-3-2017,
12.3.17,
12.3.2017,
12.03.17,
12/3/17

```
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '10-16-2003')->format('Y-m-d');
```

The closest solution that i got so far is from the following article [read the article here](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/how-i-learned-stop-using-strtotime-and-love-php-datetime)

is there a better solution, considering the fact that the input date string may be in unknown format ?

Comment: Using DateTime, DateInterval & DateTimeZone classes is the best solution imo. And if you work a lot with dates you can consider this component : https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon (it has usefull methods)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you. In `dateFormat()` function you can assign different type of valid format.

```
function dateFormat() {
    $date_format['d.m.Y'] = 'd.m.Y';
    $date_format['d.m.y'] = 'd.m.y';
    $date_format['d-m-Y'] = 'd-m-Y';
    $date_format['d-m-y'] = 'd-m-y';
    $date_format['d/m/Y'] = 'd/m/Y';
    $date_format['d/m/y'] = 'd/m/y';

    return $date_format;
}
```

After that you use this function as below code

```
$source = '2017-03-31';
$date = new DateTime($source);
$date_format = dateFormat();
foreach($date_format as $k => $v) {
    $date_list[] = $date->format($k); 
}
print_r($date_list);
exit;
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 31.03.2017
    [1] => 31.03.17
    [2] => 31-03-2017
    [3] => 31-03-17
    [4] => 31/03/2017
    [5] => 31/03/17
)
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/765415)